# Django : how to display images from database in template?

Tags: python, django, image, templates, django-templates

Hi I don't know why but I can't display images from my database. I think it is because of my path in my template.

My model :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auteur = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date de publication')
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categorie = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="culture")
    contenu = models.CharField(max_length=200000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_publie', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() -datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

My view :

```
def detail(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    return render(request, 'gazette/detail.html', {'article':article})
```

My url :

`path('<int:article_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),`

Settings :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os_path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

My template :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ article.contenu }}</h1>
<ul>
 {% if article.image %}

    <img src="{{article.image.url}}" alt="{{article.titre}}" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

 {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

And :
[image: my tree view]

And what I see on my template
[image: my image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what "cannot load" mean? Also, show us the resulting HTML after loading

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your `urls.py` after `urlpatterns`

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Like that: `from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [

    path('<int:article_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`